# Nuget package to copy exe content file to project output directory

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I'm attempting to create a Nuget package that will copy an executable file to the output directory of a .Net framework library.

Here is my nuspec file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata> 
        <id>CopyExeToOutputNugetPackage</id> 
        <version>1.0.0</version> 
        <authors>Some Dude</authors>
        <owners>Some Owner</owners>
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance> 
        <description>A package to copy an exe to the output directory.</description> 
        <tags>CopyExeToOuput</tags> 
        <contentFiles> 
            <files include=".\content\test.exe" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" />           
        </contentFiles> 
    </metadata>
</package>
```

The "nuget pack" command works fine and builds my .nupkg file. I can then add the nuget project to my .Net Framework project and the test.exe file is added to my project:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="test.exe" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I can then use Visual Studio to edit the file properties to copy to the output directory and my project file is updated:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="test.exe">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

I would prefer that this last manual step is no required.

I've attempted to use a .targets file but that's either the wrong path or I never got the configuration correct.

I've also tried using the nuspec files element (instead of ):

```xml
<files>
    <file src="test.exe" target="lib\net462" />
</files>
```

With this last configuration, I get the following exception when attempting to add the nuget package to my .Net Framework v4.6.2 project:

*Failed to add reference to 'test'. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.*

Answer (score 0):

I got a working answer that uses a PowerShell script and PowerShell Tools for Visual Studio on a Microsoft forum:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cb6236e8-4705-485b-a47c-cc4dc933c92c/nuget-package-to-copy-exe-content-file-to-project-output-directory?forum=visualstudiogeneral